# right class structure of xml deserialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, serialization

I need help by deserialization xml to C# class. I have this xml structure:

```
DataResponse>
  <Data>
    <CFgroups>
      <CFgroup id="PRO" name="pro">
        <CFgroup id="T692" name="T692">
          <item>T692-002</item>
          <item>T692-003</item>
          <item>T692-004</item>
        </CFgroup>
        <CFgroup id="T693" name="T693">
          <item>T693-001</item>
          <item>T693-003</item>
          <item>T693-004</item>
        </CFgroup>
      <CFgroup id="DESIGN" name="design">
        <CFgroup id="UN101" name="UN101">
          <item>UN101-01</item>
          <item>UN101-02</item>
          <item>UN101-03</item>
        </CFgroup>
        <CFgroup id="UN111" name="UN111">
          <item>UN111-03</item>
        </CFgroup>
      </CFgroup>
    </CFgroups>
  </Data>
</DataResponse>
```

and class in asp.net c#:

```
public class CFgroup
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("CFgroup")]
    public List<CFgroup> Groups { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("item")]
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Works fine. Now I want to add parameter 'available' to 'item' element like:

```
<item available="10">T692-002</item>
<item available="13">T692-003</item>
<item available="17>T692-004</item>
```

How should I change my class? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. Below is solution:

```
public class CFgroup
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("CFgroup")]
    public List<CFgroup> Groups { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("item")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [XmlAttribute("available")]
    public string Available { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```